# Detecting the IPads/IPhone Power Button and IPad/IPhone button

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, safari

I am working with Javascript/Safari on the IPad and I notice things are a little different than on standard browsers. One of the things I was wondering if there is a keycode or mouseevent or any way of detecting when the IPad/IPod Button(the circular button with the square at the bottom) or the power button is pressed using javascript or another method?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but this isn't possible. (It's not even possible for a full-blown iOS app to detect "home" button activity.)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is just impossible to do that from a WebPage with JavaScript. Sorry to bring the bad news to you.